# Does BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT commit changes since the last commit

Tags: java, commit, abap, jco

I know When you call BAPIs in your program that change data in the SAP system, you must then call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT to write the changes to the database.

```
   JCoFunctionTemplate functionTemplate = dest.getRepository().getFunctionTemplate("BAPI_FIXEDASSET_CHANGE");      
   JCoFunction ChangeFunction = functionTemplate.getFunction();
   ...//some code
   ChangeFunction.execute(destination);

    JCoFunctionTemplate functionTemplate = dest.getRepository().getFunctionTemplate("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");   
    JCoFunction commFunct = functionTemplate.getFunction();
    commFunct.execute(destination);
```

My question is, does BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT commit all the changes since the last commit? or does it commit only the previous transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual way of dependent database operations is also known as transaction. A transaction is per definition a atomic operation on a db to keep consistent data consistent after any change. If n database operations after each other belong to a transaction, then the commit must be issued after the last successful operation. If any of n operations fail, the transaction is considered incompletely issued.  A rollback work is the usual approach for this. If You have a transaction which should be split to commit only several changes, consider redesigning Your entire approach. Or , not so nice, create a posting function module and call this in update task. Be careful with that. Oh, and I see, You call standard sap function module. Look for its parameters. It might have a flag for commit implicitly. And never forget the SAP GUI transaction "BAPI" and read the documemtation. It is very likely that Your wish is not transactional consistent therefore the bapi must do more. If something later fails, the transaction is inconsistent and therefore not committed. Mostly sap knows what their apis should do. But I doubt it when dealing with quality notifications and quality inspection lots.  :-D

Answer (score 1):

`BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` does a `COMMIT WORK` or `COMMIT WORK AND WAIT` depending on parameter `WAIT`. This means it will commit all changes to database that have not been committed yet.

So, in your example code, it will commit the changes from `BAPI_FIXEDASSET_CHANGE` but also any changes made before that, that were not yet committed.

Comment: Thanks. would you provide me with a link for this information. and My next question is, how can i commit only the last transaction ? is it possible in the first place?

Comment: In fact it commits all (pre)pending database operations of the actual LUW, in which COMMIT WORK is called.

Comment: As @icbytes correctly points out the COMMIT WORK commits everything from the current LUW (Logical Unit of Work). If you only want to commit the last transaction you need to make sure that is the only thing in the LUW. I know different ways to accomplish this in ABAP but would not know how to accomplish it using JCo. The question you would need to answer regardless is what you want to do with the pending database operations.

Answer (score 0):

It will commit whatever is there between the context of the SAP. i.e.

```
JCoContext.begin(m_jcoDestination);
// your transactions using function module
JCoFunctionTemplate functionTemplate = m_jcoDestination.getRepository().getFunctionTemplate("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");   
JCoFunction commFunct = functionTemplate.getFunction();
commFunct.execute(m_connection.getJcoDestination()); 
JCoContext.end(m_jcoDestination);
```